# How to set up Sendgrid inbound parse on production environment using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am trying to use Sendgrid Inbound Parse so that a user can reply to an email and have it automatically create a post. I was able to get it working on localhost using the Rails constructor to send emails, but am having difficulty figuring out how to get it working in production.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/

I see that Sendgrid requires a URL ("Email sent to any address in the receiving domain will be processed by Inbound Parse and POSTed to the destination URL") but I'm not sure which URL I should be providing here.

I just created a basic rails scaffold

```
rails g scaffold gratitudes
```

Can I just provide "/gratitudes" ( POST /gratitudes)? I was thinking no because I currently require a user to be logged in to post something here. Should I instead create a new route that will allow me to process the inbound email? If so, how do I set this up? I'm having difficulty figuring out what to include in the controller and routes.rb.

I also am not sure how to integrate the instructions here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html#configuration